Getting a KeyError for Pyomo optimization
I am defining an optimization problem for LV networks. My resistance and reactance matrix are 122x122 matrices. There are 122 nodes in the network.
Below is a part of the code:
Rmatrix[i,j] = np.real(Zmatrix[i,j]) #extracted from Z matrix
Xmatrix[i,j] = np.imag(Zmatrix[i,j])
model = ConcreteModel()
Nodes = [Node list]
model.nodes = Set(initialize = [Nodes])
model.Rmatrix = Param(model.nodes, model.nodes, initialize = Rmatrix, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.Xmatrix = Param(model.nodes, model.nodes, initialize = Xmatrix, within=ComplexNumbers)

I get below KeyError when executing this:
ERROR: Rule failed for Param 'Rmatrix' with index 0: KeyError: "Index '0' is
not valid for indexed component 'Rmatrix'"
ERROR: Constructing component 'Rmatrix' from data=None failed:
    KeyError: "Index '0' is not valid for indexed component 'Rmatrix'"

What am I doing wrong?
Thank You!
I defined the parameters for the optimization problem, based on the set.nodes but getting this error when defining the parameters.

I'm not sure what the intend of this is in your code (or if it is even legal code):
Nodes = [Node list]
model.nodes = Set(initialize = [Nodes])

You don't provide some of the necessary info to decipher this.  Anyhow...  I think your first challenge here is creating the pyomo objects from your data and indexing into them.  The below is a small example that might help that has a simple 2x2 matrix.
For the most part, math models (and pyomo) are tuple indexed like matrix[i, j], whereas multi-dimensional things you might bring in from python or numpy are likely multi-indexed like matrix[i][j].  Below includes a simple translator function to use as an initializer.
After you get that squared up, I'm not sure where you are going (or how to get there) with complex number usage.  AFAIK, that is not a valid domain/within for built-in sets.
Code
import pyomo.environ as pyo

mat = [[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]

nodes = list(range(2))

# make the model...
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
m.Nodes = pyo.Set(initialize=nodes)

def mat_initializer(m, i, j):
    return mat[i][j]

m.matrix = pyo.Param(m.Nodes, m.Nodes, initialize=mat_initializer)

# check it...
m.pprint()

Output
1 Set Declarations
    Nodes : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    2 : {0, 1}

1 Param Declarations
    matrix : Size=4, Index=Nodes*Nodes, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key    : Value
        (0, 0) :     1
        (0, 1) :     2
        (1, 0) :     3
        (1, 1) :     4

2 Declarations: Nodes matrix

